# statistical significance of the difference between two averages

Tags: statistics

I've got two methods to calculate a certain value for a physical problem. (The stress shielding in a bone). I've got n (=20) data points to test the two methods. The first method tells me that the average value of the n data points is x1% (=49.8%) and the standard deviation is y1% (=7.33%). The second method tells me that the average value of the n data sets is x2% (=44.2%) and the standard deviation is y2% (=6%). So there's a difference of abs(x1-x2)% (=5.6%) in the averages between the two methods.

How can I tell if this difference is statistically significant, assuming that the error between the two methods is normally distributed?

I've got the feeling that this is a problem that should already be explained somewhere else, but I can't find the right search words to find it.

EDIT: The full data set can be found here: [Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK8ZQ.png)

EDIT 2: changed data sets to data points for clarity

Comment: If you have $n = 20$ specimens with two stress measurements on each (one using each method), and if the 20 differences are normally distributed, then you should use a 'paired t test' to see whether the two methods are significantly different. // Saying you have 20 'data sets' does not seem to make sense. // Is this a textbook problem? Are the data summaries yours or from the problem? // What topics of statistical analysis have you studied recently? // The problem would be clearer if you could show the 20 pairs of measurements.

Comment: Hi Bruce, It's not a text book problem. It's an actual problem that I'm having for my thesis :) I've had a course on statistical analysis, but that's three years ago by now. I added a picture so you can see the data.

Comment: @BruceET I think I confused with the visualisation of my data. The two different data sets are 'including death zone' and 'excluding death zone'. 'Including death zone' is the first row and the third row and 'excluding death zone' is the second row and the fourth row. You took the first and the second row together and the third and the fourth row. Which gives you a perfect mix of the two methods and therefore they seem to match :)

Comment: Erasing my Comment with scrambled data to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the data are paired, since there are two types of measurements performed on each subject (in this case, a femur).  The samples are not independent; thus a paired $t$-test is appropriate.  The hypothesis to be tested is
$$H_0 : \mu_1 - \mu_2 = 0, \quad H_a : \mu_1 - \mu_2 \ne 0,$$ where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the means of the respective measurement type.  Then the
test statistic is given by $$T = \frac{\bar x_1 - \bar x_2 - 0}{s/\sqrt{n}} \sim t_{n-1},$$ where $n = 20$ is the number of paired observations in the sample, $\bar x_1$, $\bar x_2$ are the sample means of the respective measurement types, and $s$ is the sample standard deviation of the paired differences.

So, you would calculate for each femur the difference in measurements, then calculate the standard deviation of these.  Then you calculate the difference of means (or the mean of differences, it's the same).  You should get
$$s = 0.0166702, \quad \bar x_1 = 0.4975, \quad \bar x_2 = 0.4415, \quad T = 15.0232.$$  The corresponding $p$-value for the two-sided test is $$p = 5.356 \times 10^{-12},$$ which furnishes evidence to reject $H_0$:  the probability of obtaining a result as extreme as that observed if the true difference is $0$, is at most $p$, which is so small that we can be highly confident that the true mean difference is not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a two sample t test reveals a p value of $.0118$ assuming all the criteria are met for such a test. At the $.05$ significance level, with $.0118 < .05$, the difference is statistically significant. A paired t test would be more powerful in eliminating possible error but with such a small p value its very doubtful that the final outcome would be any different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil. I tried to reproduce your result of a p-value of .0118, but I couldn't. I used the two sample t test with equal variances as mentioned on this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test and this t-score calculator: http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/t-distribution.aspx, but found a t-score of 0.06. Is it correct to say that the degrees of freedom is 38 (=2n-2)?

Comment: Nevermind it turned out that that site automatically did a one tailed test. This site: https://surfstat.anu.edu.au/surfstat-home/tables/t.php gave me the same value as you for a two tailed test. I also tried a paired t-test. (given the data set: mu_d=5.6% and S_d=1.625%). This just gave me a p-score of 0. Is that possible?

Comment: @ThaNoob $p = 0$ is not possible.  However, when $p$ is *extremely* small, as it is in the case of the paired $t$-test (See my answer), most online calculators or tables cannot calculate $p$ to the necessary precision, because it involves computing the cumulative distribution function for the Student's $t$ distribution for an extremely improbable value of the test statistic.

Comment: @heropup I asssumed that it was something like that but now I'm certain. Thank you for your answer as well. To Phil: although your answer is perfectly valid I chose for heropup's answer because it's more elaborate. Many thanks to both of you!

Comment: Good, I'm glad you got a satisfactory answer. Given your data, the paired t test was the correct test to run.